# Java on RISC-V ISA

Tags: java, open-source, riscv

After much searching, I have not found a JVM that runs on the RISC-V ISA.  This seems critical for adoption.  It is difficult to see selling a RISC-V server, or tablet, or even a smart TV, without a working Java implementation.  It feels like something that the community should to come together and work on.  I am willing to pitch in.

Does anyone know of an open source project to port a JVM implementation to RISC-V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Martin Maas at UC Berkeley is doing an open source project to implement a high performance JIT for Java on RISC-V.  They plan to use either the C2 JIT optimizer or potentially see if Graal can be adapted.  Anyone interested can contact him through the UC Berkeley website and get involved.

https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~maas/

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK currently no open source JVM implementation supports RISC-V at the moment. Also most implementations are basically an interpreter and are using GNU Classpath or OpenJDK for the class libraries.

For a port to RISC-V one has to port the interpreter and the class library. As some are pure interpreters without JIT, a port could be easy. A popular implementation was JamVM. It was used in Ubuntu on ARM-CPUs as JVM.

Wikipedia has a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) of known JVM implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Latest update:

With the help of OpenJDK community, RISC-V port project lead by Huawei Technologies has been integrated and becomes a first class member of JDK 19.

Project web page: https://openjdk.java.net/projects/riscv-port

JEP: https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/422

This ported OpenJDK to a new platform: Linux/RISC-V, which supports the following subsystems:

1. The template interpreter
2. The C1 (client) JIT compiler
3. The C2 (server) JIT compiler
4. All current mainline GCs, including Z and Shenandoah.

Currently, this port only supports the RV64G configuration of RISC-V, which is the general-purpose 64-bit RISC-V ISA. In the future we may consider supporting other RISC-V configurations such as, for example, a general-purpose 32-bit configuration (RV32G).

This means that people will have an official free (as in beer) full-featured JDK 19 release for RISC-V in September 2022.